# Reshape data from wide to long (Creating Panel Data)

Tags: stata, panel

I downloaded data from data stream Refinitiv. The data is in wide format which resulted in too many variables (761). I only want to form 8 variables.

How can I do that in Stata?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAWFb.png)

I wrote this syntax

```
reshape long Date variable, i(date) j(UVBKP, PCHUVBKP1D, UVBKPA, UVBKPB, UVBKTNA, UVBKNAV, UVBKPH, UVBKPL)
```

but I don't know why it says

````
variable date not found
```
````

Comment: Your image is of a spreadsheet file, so you give no reliable information about your variable names in Stata.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to reshape your data from wide to long format in Stata, but you're encountering an issue with the "variable date not found". To successfully reshape your data, make sure that the variable names you're referencing in your `reshape` command match exactly with the variable names in your dataset.

Additionally, you can specify the `i` and `j` options to indicate the prefixes for your new long-format variables. Here's a corrected version of your syntax:

```
reshape long UVBKP PCHUVBKP1D UVBKPA UVBKPB UVBKTNA UVBKNAV UVBKPH UVBKPL, i(Date) j(Variable)
```

In this syntax, replace `Variable` with the appropriate identifier for each of the 8 variables you want to create. Make sure that `Date` matches the exact variable name for your date variable in the dataset.